# Using Browserify with a revision manifest in Gulp, getting "Error: write after end"

Tags: gulp, browser-cache, browserify, reactjs

I'm trying to compile a React app, append a hash to the output filename and produce a revision manifest, so that I can tell the browser to cache it forever. The problem is that the dozen or so tools involved don't all work together perfectly, at least as far as I can figure out by trying to assimilate all of their readmes and juggle `.pipe` calls.

Gulpfile: [gist](https://gist.github.com/d4goxn/ca8d1a47f7c7c7f17859)

Gulp task:

```js
gulp.task( 'compile:js', function() {
    var browserifyTransform = transform( function( filename ) {
        return browserify( filename )
            .transform( reactify )
            .bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src( 'src/index.js' )
        .pipe( browserifyTransform )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( rev() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'static/dist' ));
});
```

*update* Simplified version, same error:

```
gulp.task( 'compile:js', function() {
    var browserifyTransform = transform( function( filename ) {
        return browserify( filename )
            .transform( reactify )
            .bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src( 'src/index.js' )
        .pipe( browserifyTransform )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'static/dist' ));
});
```

Error stack:

```
[15:55:04] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/pixsplodr/gulpfile.js
[15:55:04] Starting 'compile:js'...

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (/home/dan/Projects/pixsplodr/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:161:12)
    at Labeled.Writable.write (/home/dan/Projects/pixsplodr/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:208:5)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:601:24)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:610:7)
    at _stream_readable.js:578:7
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solution that satisfies my requirements, but it isn't perfect.

1. Let Browserify start the stream from a file name, instead of using `gulp.src`
2. Use vinyl-source-stream to transform Browserify's Node stream to a Gulp stream, before passing the data on to other gulp plugins

I am also using gulp-rev to append a hash to generated filenames, and to create a manifest that maps them to their original filename.

I was having trouble with source maps earlier too, but I have found that using Browserify transforms and settings seems to work better than using Gulp plugins on Browserify's output. That might be entirely due to user error, but I have been seeing so many conflicting Browserify / Gulp examples and minimal examples that I was unable to extend in an intuitive way, that I am just glad to have a working build with all of the features that I wanted.

```js
var gulp = require( 'gulp' );
var gutil = require( 'gulp-util' );
var watchify = require( 'watchify' );
var browserify = require( 'browserify' );
var source = require( 'vinyl-source-stream' );
var buffer = require( 'vinyl-buffer' );
var sass = require( 'gulp-sass' );
var _ = require( 'lodash' );
var rev = require( 'gulp-rev' );

// Dev build
gulp.task( 'watch', [ 'sass' ], function() {
    gulp.watch( 'node_modules/quiz/style/**/*.scss', [ 'sass' ]);
    builder( './src/app/index.js', true ).bundle( './dist/static', 'quiz-app.min.js' );
});

// Production build
gulp.task( 'build', [ 'sass' ], function() {
    builder( './src/app/index.js', false ).bundle( './dist/static', 'quiz-app.min.js' );
});

// snip //

function builder( entry, isDev ) {
    var bundler;

    if( isDev ) {
        bundler = watchify( browserify(
            './src/app/index.js',
            _.extend( watchify.args, { debug: true })
        ));
    } else {
        bundler = browserify(
            './src/app/index.js'
        );
    }

    bundler.transform( 'reactify' );
    bundler.transform( 'es6ify' );
    bundler.transform({ global: true }, 'uglifyify' );

    bundler.on( 'log', gutil.log ); // Help bundler log to the terminal

    function bundle( dest, filename ) {
        return bundler.bundle()
        .on( 'error', gutil.log.bind( gutil, 'Browserify error' )) // Log errors during build
        .pipe( source( filename ))
        .pipe( buffer() )
        .pipe( rev() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( dest ))
        .pipe( rev.manifest() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( dest ));
    }

    return { bundle: bundle };
}
```

I also tried just using the tools from NPM scripts, but I was unable to find a good way to do incremental builds while watching a set of files.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few open bugs that result in this error (example: github.com/hughsk/vinyl-transform/issues/1). The problem with them is that when the original src stream ends, it ends the writable stream, which is still being used. Hence the error. 
Try this instead.

```
gulp.task( 'compile:js', function() {
    var browserifyTransform = transform( function( filename ) {
        return browserify( filename )
            .transform( reactify )
            .bundle();
    });

    gulp.src( 'src/index.js' )
        .pipe( browserifyTransform )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
        .pipe( uglify() )
        .pipe( rev() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'static/dist' ));

    return gulp.src( '');
});
```

By returning a seperate gulp.src, gulp is forced to wait until the initial command is finished in order to return the new src.

Comment: I still get the same error. After trying with the extra `gulp.src`, I also tried removing all of the `.pipe` calls except `browserifyTransform` and `gulp.dest`, which also did not change the error. So, I think the problem is with how I am using Browserify. The examples I have been finding are a little confusing, because of the recent change where browserify no longer accepts options in its constructor. I guess a bunch of stuff was moved out of browserify and into external "transforms", which is cool, but the only new example I have found is not working for me.

Comment: I wish I could find a single, authoritative, up to date specification for how to combine all this stuff together, but I also wish I was an astronaut. Nothing good is ever easy.

Comment: Update: Removing `.transform( reactify )` from `browserifyTransform` and removing all JSX from my project makes the build work. A pyrrhic victory.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue using [gulp-streamify](https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-streamify) package.

I had to rewrite my task as follow:

```
gulp        = require('gulp');
rev         = require('gulp-rev');          // add hash to filename
rimraf      = require('gulp-rimraf');       // delete folder
gulpsync    = require('gulp-sync')(gulp);   // sync gulp task 
babel       = require('gulp-babel');        // es6 transpiler
browserify  = require('browserify');        
source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
streamify   = require('gulp-streamify');


gulp.task('compile-es6', function(){
  var stream =  browserify('app/assets/javascript/application.js')
    .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})
    .bundle();

  return stream.pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(streamify(rev()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/javascripts'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest('./rev-manifest.json',{merge:true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});
```